# The "allow apps downloaded from" setting won't stay selected

Tags: macos, time-machine, security

All my (downloaded?) files restored from Time Machine are marked as "damaged". I assume the problem is similar to this one: [All downloaded files cannot be opened as they are 'damaged and should be moved to the Trash'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175634/97232) so I try to change the "Allow app..." setting.

I open Security & Privacy and see App Store is selected:
[image: App Store is selected]

I click the padlock and check "App Store and identified developers":
[image: Authenticate and select new option]
(I also notice that "Anywhere" is no longer an option.)

I leave System Preferences and try to open my files, but still get the error. So I go back to System Preferences, Security & Privacy and the old option is still selected:
[image]

Comment: I know you fixed this by reinstalling, but for posterity, the less-brute-force solution would have probably been something in here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/07/06/sticky-preferences-why-trashing-or-editing-them-may-not-change-anything/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a new Mac and nothing was working anyway, I decided I had nothing to lose by wiping it and starting over. So I restarted it and held down Command + R. From the menu I selected to reinstall macOS. After waiting 40 minutes I was disappointed to see that this option did not wipe the drive, and my restored accounts were still there on the login screen. I was about to restart again and this time format the drive, but I thought What the heck, and logged into my account. Surprisingly none of the files I opened were reported as damaged! Everything seems to be working now.